# Ejecutar INNER JOIN con dos tablas en una función PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ejecutar un simple INNER JOIN con dos tabla en una función PostgreSQL?

Lo que quiero es ejecutar esta misma función pero con dos tablas haciendo un `INNER JOIN`, pero esto solo funciona con una tabla y no me sirve de nada. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
create  or  replace  function test()
returns  setof categorias  as $$
begin
  return query
execute 'select * from categorias'
  return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: lo que quiero es ejecutar esta misma funcion pero con dos tablas haciendo un INNER JOIN pero esto solo funciona con una tabla y no me sirve de nada de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es como sigue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION categorias_articulos() 
RETURNS TABLE (categoria_nombre varchar, articulo_nombre varchar) AS $$

BEGIN        
  FOR categoria_nombre, articulo_nombre IN 

     SELECT categorias.categoria_nombre ,  articulos.articulo_nombre 

        FROM categorias

             JOIN articulos

             ON categorias.categoria_id = articulos.categoria_id

  LOOP

    RETURN NEXT;

  END LOOP;

  RETURN;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: OK por lo visto tuve que resolverlo yo mismo aqui esta el codigo para un JOIN CON dos Tablas

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, yo pase por el mismo problema y esta fue mi solución, muy similar a la de arriba.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.buscarporcategoria(IN _categoria_ character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE (isbn character varying, titulo character varying, edicion INT4, paginas INT4, fecha DATE, nombre character varying, apellido character varying, categoria character varying, editorial character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $$

BEGIN
    FOR nombre, apellido, isbn, titulo, edicion, paginas, fecha, categoria, editorial IN
        SELECT 
            autores.nombre, autores.apellido,
            libros.isbn, libros.titulo, 
            libros.edicion, libros.paginas, libros.fecha_publicacion,
            categorias.categoria,         
            editoriales.editorial
            FROM autores
            INNER JOIN libros_por_autor ON autores.id = libros_por_autor.id_autores
            INNER JOIN libros ON libros.id = libros_por_autor.id_libros
            INNER JOIN libros_por_categoria ON libros_por_categoria.id_libros = libros.id
            INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = libros_por_categoria.id_categorias
            INNER JOIN libros_por_editorial ON libros_por_editorial.id_libros = libros.id
            INNER JOIN editoriales ON editoriales.id = libros_por_editorial.id_editoriales        
            WHERE categorias.categoria ILIKE '%'||_categoria_||'%'
        LOOP
            RETURN NEXT;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$;
```

--Luego solo la mandas a llamar

```
SELECT * FROM buscarporcategoria('r');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function ver_proveedor_del_producto ()

  returns table (
        num_venta int, 
        nombre varchar(25)
      ) as
$$
    select ventas.num_venta, productos.nombre
    from ventas, productos_ventas, productos
    where fk_ventas = ventas.num_venta and fk_productos = productos.sku;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Una respuesta que es puro código, sin ninguna explicación no es de utilidad.